# помогите c# ds api

Tags: c#, .net, api, discord

мне нужно чтобы бот для дс ждал смс от человек например введите имя я ввожу его и он просит у тебя ввести возраст а после этого скидывает тебе ответы с твоим именем возрастом и допустим половину твоего возрасста

---

```
namespace Discord_Bot_Tut
{
    class Program
    {
        DiscordSocketClient client;
        static void Main(string[] args)
            => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        private async Task MainAsync()
        {
            client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            client.MessageReceived += CommandsHandler;
            client.Log += Log;

            var token = "token tut";

            await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await client.StartAsync();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private Task Log(LogMessage msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private Task CommandsHandler(SocketMessage msg)
        {
            if (!msg.Author.IsBot && msg.Content == "!newstats")
            {
                msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Привет, введите ник игрока");



                
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

вот код

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Это зовется "интерактивностью". Раньше, за это отвечал отдельный пакет (`Discord.Addons.Interactive`), вам достаточно было его поставить через NuGet, унаследовать класс команд от `InteractiveBase`, а не `ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>`, указать команде, что она асинхронная (`RunMode = RunMode.Async` в атрибуте) и все, вам доступны были новые методы, включая нужный вам (`NextMessageAsync()`). Увы, этот пакет давно заброшен, а с выходом Discord.net v3 вовсе перестал работать. Но, вроде как, энтузиасты подправили его, выпустив `Discord.InteractivityAddon` в NuGet, так что пробуйте...